# Callable blocking UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callable

I've been downloading and parsing a webpage with Jsoup, to show the content in a list. This process takes a while so I implemented [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface to do the task in another thread and get the result back.
The problem is that it still blocks UI during the process.

```
public class GetListaNotizie implements Callable<ArrayList<Notizia>> {

 static ArrayList<Notizia> getNotizieBySezione() {
    [...] Long process 
    return notizie;
 }

 @Override
 public ArrayList<Notizia> call() throws Exception {
    return getNotizieBySezione();
 }
}
```

And then:

```
final ExecutorService service;
final Future<ArrayList<Notizia>> task;
service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
task = service.submit(new GetListaNotizie());
try {
    ArrayList<Notizia> notizie = task.get();
    lvListaNotizie.setAdapter(new RiempiLista(activity, notizie));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `task.get()` call is blocking. Anyway, you don't need to reinvent the wheel using executors and futures. Android already has a [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class which is made *precisely* for these kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ... you're submitting your `Callable` to the pool, then explicitly blocking the thread waiting for it to finish.

```
ArrayList<Notizia> notizie = task.get();
```

**I missed the Android tag on your Q**. You're re-inventing the wheel here. Android provides [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for exactly this use case. See the AsyncTask example under [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for an example of how it works.

(*original answer follows*)

---

You need your `Callable` to update/notify the UI when it's finished. One possible approach would be to pass a reference to the list you mention to your `Callable`.

**Edit to add from comments:**

Right now, you submit your `Callable` to the pool. Then you sit there waiting for it to finish (blocking the UI thread). Then you do this:

```
lvListaNotizie.setAdapter(new RiempiLista(activity, notizie));
```

Pass `lvListaNotizie` to your `GetListaNotizie` via a constructor and have that happen at the end of `call()` instead of returning the list to the `Future`. I don't know what `lvListaNotizie` is; if it's not thread-safe you will want to synchronize on it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you said. Could you please write an example?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is deprecated since API level 30.

You can use coroutines [documentation link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) for async code
or you can use work manager for async long-running operations [documentation link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqp-LBhDQARIsAO0a6aLUboBU3uejFI1o3eR1ooeQz0ENIsIVUPwrGfqchbi3d3rpZf8jzEMaAiTBEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

it is too late to answer but may be useful for new developers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).